# How do I use the Bing Search API in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, bing-api, azure-marketplace

I'm trying to use the Bing Search API to find images as backgrounds to the tiles inside of my app. I've included the BingSearchContainer.cs in my Project but I can't make it work with the sample code provided here.

Any guidelines for how to use the Bing Search API inside of my Windows Phone 8 app would be appriciated!

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I expect that you already have a AccountKey so I wont tell you have to get one.

### Implementation

1. First of all, add the [BingSearchContainer.cs](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/explore/getproxy/5ba839f1-12ce-4cce-bf57-a49d98d29a44) to your project
2. Implement the sample C# code found in the [Bing API Quick Start & Code](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=272626&clcid=0x409)
3. Thereafter, right-click **References** and choose **Manage NuGet Packages...** and search for, and install, `Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.WindowsP`.
4. Modify the sample code so that it work with Windows Phone:

   ```
   using Bing;
   using System;
   using System.Data.Services.Client;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Net;

   namespace StackOverflow.Samples.BingSearch
   {
       public class Finder
       {
           public void FindImageUrlsFor(string searchQuery)
           {
               // Create a Bing container. 
               string rootUri = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search";
               var bingContainer = new Bing.BingSearchContainer(new Uri(rootUri));
               bingContainer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

               // Replace this value with your account key. 
               var accountKey = "YourAccountKey";

               // Configure bingContainer to use your credentials. 
               bingContainer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(accountKey, accountKey);

               // Build the query. 
               var imageQuery = bingContainer.Image(query, null, null, null, null, null, null);

               imageQuery.BeginExecute(_onImageQueryComplete, imageQuery);

           }

           // Handle the query callback. 
           private void _onImageQueryComplete(IAsyncResult imageResults)
           {
               // Get the original query from the imageResults.
               DataServiceQuery<Bing.ImageResult> query =
                   imageResults.AsyncState as DataServiceQuery<Bing.ImageResult>;

               var resultList = new List<string>();

               foreach (var result in query.EndExecute(imageResults))
                   resultList.Add(result.MediaUrl);

               FindImageCompleted(this, resultList);
           }

           public event FindImageUrlsForEventHandler FindImageUrlsForCompleted;
           public delegate void FindImageUrlsForEventHandler(object sender, List<string> result);
       }
   }
   ```

### Example

1. And now, let's use the code I provided you with:

   ```
   using Bing;
   using System;
   using System.Data.Services.Client;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Net;

   namespace StackOverflow.Samples.BingSearch
   {
       public class MyPage
       {
           private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
           {
               var finder = new Finder();
               finder.FindImageUrlsForCompleted += finder_FindImageUrlsForCompleted;
               finder.FindImageUrlsFor("candy");
           }

           void finder_FindImageUrlsForCompleted(object sender, List<string> result)
           {
               Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
               {
                   foreach (var s in result)
                       MyTextBox.Text += s + "\n";
               });
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I want to integrate same api in iOS application.Can u please tell me which account we should have? and Where we can register for it? Thank u.

Comment: I want to add that you should set bingContainer.UseDefaultCredentials = false , as explained on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/c01c0b62-c084-4983-b6d7-38a9eed2c17c/bing-api-from-windows-phone-8-app?forum=DataMarket.

Comment: I've implemented it now, @redtuna