# Bing Api on Windows Phone 7 (DataService Client)

Tags: c#, api, windows-phone-7, bing, bing-api

Firstly sorry for my fatal english.

I got problem with Bing Search Api on Windows Phone 7. I've added BingSearchContainer.cs file from Bing.com/Developers, but it's need reference to System.Data.Service.Client. I've finded two .dll files. First was almost good, but DataServiceContext class (which is base class for BingSearchContainer class from this file from bing.com) wasn't have Credentials property. So I was searching more I find information about OData liblary for Windows Phone 7. There is the same problem and i have extra problem, because this .dll don't have DataServiceQuery.

Anybody know where i can find good System.Data.Service.Client.dll file for Bing Search API? I spent two day over that problem and nothing.

Comment: It ships with the framework.  You'll find it exactly in the same place as mscorlib.dll.  If you can't add a reference to it within visual studio, BingSearchContainer is probably not written against the WP7 version of the framework.  That means you have a much bigger issue than this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122037/how-do-i-use-the-bing-search-api-in-windows-phone